# How do i serialize/deserialize GTLDriveFile Object into pList

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I'm using google drive files in my application. Accessing files, downloading files, uploading files are working as a charm. Now I'm trying to save the GTLDriveFile information on local(pList) by using NSCoding. Can you please help me to save this information into pList or suggest the best way to store this info in local

Steps followed:

1. Google Authentication - done
2. Querying Files - done
3. Trying to save all file information into pList - I'm here now

Please refer this link for **GTLDriveFile** Class Structure
https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_drive_file

I've tried by this way, but i couldn't save the entire structure into it.

For Ex: .h file

```
#import "GTLDriveFile.h"

@interface sample : GTLDriveFile <NSCoding>

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "sample.h"

@implementation sample

//@synthesize File;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super init])    {
         super.fileSize=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"fileSize"];
         super.originalFilename=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"originalFilename"];
         super.mimeType=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"mimeType"];
         super.title=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
         **super.parents=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"parents"];**
         super.lastModifyingUserName=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"lastModifyingUserName"];
         **super.copyable=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"copyable"];**
         super.kind=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"kind"];
         super.writersCanShare=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"writersCanShare"];
         **super.appDataContents=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"appDataContents"];
         super.modifiedDate=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"modifiedDate"];**
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject: super.fileSize forKey:@"fileSize"];
    [encoder encodeObject: super.originalFilename forKey:@"originalFilename"];
    [encoder encodeObject: super.mimeType forKey:@"mimeType"];
    [encoder encodeObject: super.title forKey:@"title"];
    **[encoder encodeObject: super.parents forKey:@"parents"];**
    [encoder encodeObject: super.lastModifyingUserName forKey:@"lastModifyingUserName"];
    **[encoder encodeObject:copyable forKey:@"copyable"];**
    [encoder encodeObject: super.kind forKey:@"kind"];
    [encoder encodeObject: super.writersCanShare forKey:@"writersCanShare"];
    **[encoder encodeObject:appDataContents forKey:@"appDataContents"];**
    **[encoder encodeObject: super.modifiedDate forKey:@"modifiedDate"];**
}

@end
```

Problem was, i couldn't serialize/de-serialize the direct values like NSString, NSNUMBER, and etc. When I'm trying on some base object like "**copyable**", I'm getting an exception(please refer the bolded objects or refer the GTLDriveFile class reference from the above link).

Guys, please help me to save this info to local and suggest the best way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what your question is. What are you trying to encode? Show that code. None of the code you show refers to `NSCoding` so what do you expect to implement it?

Comment: Sorry. and I followed initwithCoder and encodewithcoder mechanism.. its working fine for NSString and not working for NSArray @Wain

Comment: - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super init])    {
        name=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
       array = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:nsarray forKey:@"nsarray"];
}   but How am i Encode and decode other class Object.? @Wain

Comment: Please [edit] your encoding and decoding methods into your question - the formatting is lost in comments.

Comment: Is that your actual code?  You are using different key and variable names in each method, so I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

So Cocoa framework classes support `NSCoding`. Of these classes, some are 'plain' classes (like `NSString`) and they support everything that's required. Some are 'complex' classes (like `NSArray`) which contain instances of other classes - in this case, all of the contained objects *must* support `NSCoding` for the encoding to work properly.

Any non-framework class that you want to encode / decode, you need to specify that it conforms to `NSCoding` and you need to write an implementation of the protocol methods (calling `super` if appropriate).

Comment: if a class contain NSArray as property how can we Archive this @wain

Comment: @ShaikMohaideen ... he says how to do it in his answer, did you even read it?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin we can Do NSCoding For NSString and Otherdata types but am not sure about NSArray

Comment: @ShaikMohaideen again READ wain's answer. Quite clearly says how to handle `NSArray`'s and the classes it contains. I'm not going to repeat his instructions

Answer (score 1):

In one of your comments, above, you effectively suggested the following `NSCoder` methods (clearly assuming you're dealing with an object with only two properties, `name` and `array`):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.name  = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        self.array = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name  forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.array forKey:@"array"]; 
}
```

That's basically right if the super class does not, itself, conform to `NSCoder`. But if `super` conforms to `NSCoder`, you have to give it a chance to do its magic, too:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        self.name  = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        self.array = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];

    [encoder encodeObject:self.name  forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.array forKey:@"array"];
}
```

If you're subclassing some custom object (e.g. whether `GTLObject` or one of your own classes), it's critical to use that this also conforms to `NSCoder`. And you have to repeat this above pattern in all of your classes that will be included in the archive. But the Cocoa classes (like `NSArray`) already conform to `NSCoder`, so you only have to worry about your own classes.